# python PBKDF pkcs12 implementation

Tags: python, cryptography, pkcs#12

Is there any python PBKDF (pkcs12) implementation?
Please, note that I'm not looking for PBKDF1 or PBKDF2 (pkcs5) implementation, but for pkcs12 one.
They are supposed to be different, as it is mentioned in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9631128/are-there-any-published-extensions-to-pkcs12).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After googling around, unfortunately, I didn't find the solution in the pure python. However I did find a couple of C libraries, that support PBKDF PKCS #12 and have the python bindings - [Crypto](http://www.cryptopp.com/), [CyaSSL](https://github.com/cyassl/cyassl/). None of the bindings supports the required algorithm though. That's why I decided to pick one lib up and wrap the algorithm by myself: https://github.com/cyassl/cyassl/pull/55

Answer (score -1):

There is a python pakage at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PBKDF. i had used it

Comment: According to the package description, the PBKDF package supports only PKCS#5, not PKCS12.